# WebStorm: bash script errors when run with "run", but works when executed in the console

Tags: bash, webstorm

I wrote a build script for my project (maven, grunt as well as some server-reconfiguration), and when I use the WebStorm command-line with

```
~/Projects/javaee-angularjs$ ./launchServer.sh
```

Everything works as expected.

However, when I configure the file to be run by WebStorm (the green triangle top-right) it fails because of: `/home/user/Projects/javaee-angularjs/launchServer.sh: line 29: grunt: command not found`

The run-config should be absolutely correct:
working directory is the correct one and the script is found to begin with.

Any Idea what could cause this weird behavior?

P.S. I don't know whether WebStorm can run bash natively, since I've always had the bash plugin installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try starting WebStorm from terminal - does the issue persist?

When being launched from desktop/System menu, WebStorm only sees environment variables configured in `~/.profile` (login shell), but not in interactive shell configuration files (like `~/.bashhrc`). Possible workarounds:

- Workaround 1: make required variables available in a login shell (i.e. for bash, move them from `.bashrc` to `.bash_profile`).
- Workaround 2: run IDE from a terminal, via `bin/webstorm.sh`
- Workaround 3: edit the desktop launcher and set command to `/bin/bash -l -i -c "/path/to/webstorm.sh"`

see also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7589

Answer (score 2):

The error sounds like Webstorm cannot find grun in its path.  Try using the full path to the grunt command.

Comment: its a bash script.
The bash interpreter is looking for grunt.
And it's finding it when ran in console

Comment: Yes, but if your PATH and Webstorm's PATH are different, then grunt may be found when you run it in your console, but not when Webstorm runs it.  Remember, the two environments may not be the same.

Comment: "from the run config of the script: "Working directory: <the correct directory>"
And everything else should be bash's problem (which is universal as far as I know):
The script itself even checks if it's in the right directory (and that test gets through)

Comment: as @Lewis M said, it seems you don't understand how bash find program. Try in a new shell a the same location: `export PATH=;./launchServer.sh `.